# How does one come to the conclusion that the data is "Unrelational"

Tags: sql, modeling, rdbms, nosql

What sort of pointers, facets, characteristics or structures should one analyse to determine that a given colletion of objects fits bets in a relational store or a Non-relational one? and further, how does one determine that he should use a document store over a KVP store?!?